# Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateExists.types, does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, validation

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ItemRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return Auth::check();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */

    //  validasi data
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nama' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'type_id' => 'required|integer|exists.types,'.$this->id,
            'brand_id' => 'required|integer|exists.brands,'.$this->id,
            'photos' => 'nullable|array',
            'photos.*' => 'nulable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
            'features' => 'nullable|string',
            'price' => 'required|numeric',
            'star' => 'nullable|numeric',
            'review' => 'nullable|numeric'
        ];
    }
}
```

I have a problem in my Request. In validation data `exists.types` does not exist.
How to solve this error?
Thank you.

Comment: Reading the manual should help: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#basic-usage-of-exists-rule

Comment: _Side note:_ On `photos.*`, you have a typo: `nulable` should be `nullable`.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you provided, `exists.brands`, is not a valid Laravel validation rule.

The correct syntax for the exists validation rule is `exists:table,column`. Therefore, the correct syntax for validating that a value exists in the name column of the brands table would be:

```
$request->validate([
    'name' => 'exists:brands,name',
]);
```

Comment: While correct, we usually don't answer questions caused by a typo but vote to close or flag. Those questions are of no real use to other users